# Gamepad not being detected properly

Tags: windows-xp, usb, drivers, game-controller

I have a standard USB gamepad; two analogue sticks with push-to-fire, d-pad, four buttons on the right, shoulder buttons in pairs, etc.

When I plug it into a Windows XP box it's detected as a 'Dual Analog Pad'. The left analogue stick works properly, and shows up as a joystick. However, the right analogue stick does not, and instead appears as two individual analogue axes labelled 'Z Axis' and 'Z Rotation'. (Everything else works fine.)

Because Windows doesn't report my gamepad as having two joysticks, this means that any apps that expect to see two joysticks don't think that my gamepad is compatible and so don't work.

I can't find any way to tell Windows that my gamepad does, in fact, have two joysticks. Any ideas?

Comment: This is correct and normal behavior.

Comment: More information?

Comment: because it is comming in like any 4 axis type of joystick, like a flight stick, if the games support the other 2 axis, then it doesnt much matter what winders called them. Having the exact driver from the manufacture , might show it different, and between the game and the driver you can set them to do different things. EX: with my flightstick I can actually set many games up to use the Throttle as W&S, More complex Software provided by manufacture, can even set it up as W&S with a RUN tossed in at full throttle. Just depends. To get more control, get any drivers/software they have.

Comment: Well, yeah, except I don't have a joystick (which has one XY control and a bunch of independent analogue controls). Instead I have a gamepad, which has *two* XY controls (and a bunch of independent analogue controls). I'm trying to use it with software that's expecting to see a device with two XY controls, and of course it's not working. Said software doesn't appear to be configurable, hence my desire to configure Windows to report the gamepad differently. Does anyone actually know how to do this?

Comment: Understood. A) the driver Which identifies to the system the configuration. Also windows provides a generic set of configs that you can load in also.  B) some software provided by the device maker that does other configurating. C) the game itself, and that working together in combination. I know how to do it with my input devices, not yours, but we do not even know what yours is?  Please ammend the question with what the manufacture of the device is, and the software they supply.  ???

Comment: (a) Windows is detecting the device as a 'dual analogue gamepad', so I would expect Windows to show two analogue sticks. (b) none. No driver was supplied; this is the generic Windows driver only. (c) n/a at this point, as the Windows control panel joystick test thingy is showing the misdetected axes.

Comment: I am looking in the XP Control pannel Game controller location, in ADD, where it shows "Two 2-Axis 2 button joystick on one gameport", and "Custom". In there we are supposed to be able to configure a generic controller. And it brings back memories, of what a pain it can be to force it to do what I wanted.

Comment: in the gamport.ini are the old audio board gameport installs :-(, , DImaps.ini is the install for many direct input devices. this file used Hardware IDs to install the INI for specific game controllers. In there it points to specific IniFiles, for install, which again use PID and VID tags. Potentially you could find out the full ID of the device you have, then find a appropriate INI that matches the config, then alter the ID data to match the ID of your device. then attempt to use thier configurations for your device. for me it would be a little thick.